# Boost non-copyable weirdness

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, noncopyable

I have a class inheriting from `boost::noncopyable`; say, with header excerpt as follows:

```
class A : boost::noncopyable {
   ...
   blah
   ...
private:
   struct impl;
   boost::scoped_ptr<impl> m_impl;
};
```

Then in one of the projects of my solution, I have a class (that also happens to inherit from `boost::noncopyable`), one whose private members in an implementation detail is a reference to an object of type A, say, in the header excerpt:

```
class B : boost::noncopyable {
   ...
   blah
   ...
private:
   struct impl;
   boost::scoped_ptr<impl> m_impl;
};
```

and in the implementation excerpt (cpp):

```
struct B::impl {
    impl(A& a) : m_a(a) {}
    set_A(A& a) {m_a = a;}
    A& m_a;
    ...
}

B(A& a) : m_impl(new impl(a)) {}
...
```

Then in another project of my solution, I have a class C inheriting from B, say, with a header excerpt:

```
class C : public B {
   ...
   blah;
   ...
private: 
   struct impl;
   boost::scoped_ptr<impl> m_impl;
};
```

and in the implementation excerpt (cpp):

```
struct C::impl {
    impl(A& a) : m_a(a) {}
    void set_A(A& a) {m_a = a;}
    A& m_a;
};

C(A &a) : B(a), m_impl(new impl(a)) {}
...
```

But when I try to build in MSVC++ 2008, I get the following error:

```
error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::operator ='
error C2248: 'boost::scoped_ptr<T>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::scoped_ptr<T>' with T = A::impl
This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'A& A::operator =(const A&)'
```

The compiler only has an issue with C's `set_A` function, not B's `set_A`. Appreciate if anyone has any ideas on this and can shed some light? Thanks as always for your interest.

### Edit:

To summarize, what I don't understand here is why the compiler is picky about when to apply the error regarding `boost::noncopyable`. When I comment out the `set_A(..)` function in class C, everything compiles OK. But when I keep it, it gives the error, whereas it doesn't have any problems with the same in class B. I also edited the error message above slightly to give more detail. I note here that it stated something about a compiler generated function. Could it be that this happened only with class C for some reason? Why?

Comment: Are you sure those implementation `struct` members are of type `A&`, i.e. a reference, and not just `A`?

Comment: Yes.. that is critical to my implementation.

Comment: Maybe this is a compiler bug? Given just the `A` and `B` definitions, neither clang nor GCC will compile it - they both (rightly) error out in `B::set_A` (because `A`'s assignment operator is private).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EDIT]

First of all,  now I better understand your question, but I still do not understand why don't you want to change your implementation to:

```
struct C::impl {
    impl(A& a) : m_a(&a) {}
    void set_A(A& a) {m_a = &a;}
    A* m_a;
};
```

With `A` non-copyable this will simple do not work:

```
void set_A(A& a) {m_a = a;}
```

---

Anyway:

This error:

> error C2248: 'boost::scoped_ptr::operator =' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'boost::scoped_ptr' with T =
>   A::impl

is because `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` is non-copyable and this fact is not related to the fact that your `A` class is not copyable.

This error:

> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'A&
>   A::operator =(const A&)'

is for sure because of one of `XXX::set_A(A& a) { m_A = a; }` functions. In such function `A::operator =(const A&)` is required - and because it is not defined compiler try to define the default one. Default one will copy members one by one - and one of `A` members is non-copyable `boost::scoped_ptr<A::impl>`.

Then the most important for you question - why only one error - not for both `XXX::set_A(A& a) { m_A = a; }` methods?

I tested simplified version of your case in my g++ 4.5.x enviroment. The diagnosis is very similar to yours - and the effect is very similar - only one `set_A` function is complained - the first one. **This is because `A& operator = (const A&)` is needed for both - but generate only for the first one.** g++ gives the excelent diagnosis:

> ```
> ../src/AnExample.cpp:24:32: note: synthesized method 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' first required here
> ```

My example and diagnosis:

```
class noncopyable {
private:
   noncopyable(const noncopyable&);
   noncopyable& operator = (const noncopyable&);
};

class A {
  noncopyable m;
};

class B {
  B(A& a) : a(a) {}
  void set_A(A& a) { this->a = a; } // line 24
  A& a;
};

class C {
  C(A& a) : a(a) {}
  void set_A(A& a) { this->a = a; }
  A& a;
};
```

---

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/AnExample.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/AnExample.d" -MT"src/AnExample.d" -o "src/AnExample.o" "../src/AnExample.cpp"
../src/AnExample.cpp: In member function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)':
../src/AnExample.cpp:15:17: error: 'noncopyable& noncopyable::operator=(const noncopyable&)' is private
../src/AnExample.cpp:18:9: error: within this context
../src/AnExample.cpp: In member function 'void B::set_A(A&)':
../src/AnExample.cpp:24:32: note: synthesized method 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' first required here 
make: *** [src/AnExample.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target `src/AnExample.o' failed
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I agree with your comments and no, I am not confusing usage of references. However, your post doesn't quite answer my specific question about why the compiler error is only showing up at the second class's set function? I would've expected it to throw the compiler error at both places, however my VC++ 2008 project with class B defined compiles just fine!